# Clickable link inside message discord.py

Tags: python, hyperlink, discord, discord.py

I would like my bot to send message into chat like this:

```
await ctx.send("This country is not supported, you can ask me to add it here")
```

But to make "here" into clickable link, In HTML I would do it like this, right?

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/" > This country is not supported, you can ask me to add it here </a>
```

How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the other answer explained, you can't add hyperlinks in normal messages, but you *can* in Embeds. I don't see why you wouldn't want to use an Embed for an error message, especially considering it adds more functionality, so you should consider using that.

```
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.description = "This country is not supported, you can ask me to add it [here](your_link_goes_here)."
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Feel free to mess around with the Embed & add some fields, a title, a colour, and whatever else you might want to do to make it look better. More info in the relevant [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed).

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the title? I tried this but it didn't work in the title

Comment: @F.M Yes, but not using the same ``[notation](with brackets)``. When you create the Embed, you can pass in a hyperlink through the `URL` parameter. `embed = discord.Embed(url="YOUR_LINK_HERE")`, and it will put the link on the title.

Comment: But that makes the whole title the same link, I was wondering if I could make different words different links.

Comment: @F.M No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know, Discord don't allow using HTML in messages, when you see any form of formating on some messages it's either :

1. Done with markdown
2. Embed usage.

The problem is that both those methods won't help you to solve your problem, because :

1. in markdown we use `[Here](link)` to achieve what you want, but after i tried it on Discord, it doesn't seem to render, so my guess is that not all markdown is usable in Discord
2. Embeds are really different from what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this; you can add `url=(pop_in_link)`, but this one works when you do, import discord. You can use either method

Answer (score 0):

This might help people trying to embed links in their code for their bot.

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    title="[title]", 
    url="[URL]", 
    description="[description (optional)]", 
    color=[color hex code or tag (optional)]
)
```