# Storing dictionaries in json file

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to store dictionaries in a JSON file which user input. The code is:

```
@client.command()
async def shibaku0(ctx, coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6, shibakunumber, oslink):
  
    
    await ctx.message.delete()
    
    with open('Shibaku0.json', 'r') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
    coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]["coins"] = (coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6)
    shibakunumber[str(ctx.author.id)]["shibakunumber"] = (shibakunumber)
    oslink[str(ctx.author.id)]["oslink"] = (oslink)
    
    with open('Shibaku0.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(coins_data, f)
    

    embed=discord.Embed(title="Shibaku0", url=f'{oslink}', description=f'No. {shibakunumber}')
    embed.add_field(name="Coins: ", value=f'{coin1} {coin2} {coin3} {coin4} {coin5} {coin6}', inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author.name}'s Shibaku")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I want to store the "coins", "shibakunumber, "oslink", but I am getting this error message when I try and run the code:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: A valid JSON file usually starts with `{` or `[`. In case of `{`, this is and object which is similar to a `dict` in python. Starting with `[` means that it is an array like `list` in python.

Comment: So which bracket do I need to change for it to work? @MYousefi

Comment: What is the your data supposed to look like? Is it a single entity or is it a list of entities each with their own id and coins?

Comment: Basically I want to look like: " userid: { coins: "value", shibakunumber: "value" oslink: "link format" " This is because I want to be able to individually call each item @MYousefi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a json that is an associative array (JSON object / dict). You need to have `{` or a single object within the file. Each object associates `userid` with the data for that user, i.e, a nested object.

Here's a sample :

```
import json
# sample_data/Obj.json
# {
#   "user1": {"coins":  "coinstringvalue", "shibakunumber": 1, "oslink": "linkstringvalue"},
#   "user2": {"coins":  "coinstringvalue2", "shibakunumber": 2, "oslink": "linkstringvalue2"}
# }
mydata = json.load(open('sample_data/Obj.json', 'r'))
print(mydata['user1'])
print(mydata['user2'])
print(mydata['user2']['shibakunumber'])
```

This gives the output:

```
{'coins': 'coinstringvalue', 'shibakunumber': 1, 'oslink': 'linkstringvalue'}
{'coins': 'coinstringvalue2', 'shibakunumber': 2, 'oslink': 'linkstringvalue2'}
2
```

Note that the `mydata` is a `dict` type in python.

Here's an example of starting with an empty json file.

```
import json
# sample_data/empty.json
# {}

mydata = json.load(open('sample_data/empty.json', 'r'))
print(mydata)
# author_id = str(ctx.author.id)
author_id = str(1161214)
if author_id not in mydata:
  mydata[author_id] = dict()
mydata[author_id]['coins'] = ("coin1", "coin2")
mydata[author_id]['shibakunumber'] = 2
mydata[author_id]['oslink'] = "somelink"

json.dump(mydata, open('sample_data/new_file.json', 'w'))
loaded_data = json.load(open('sample_data/new_file.json', 'r'))

print(loaded_data)
```

Produces:

```
mydata {}
loaded_data {'1161214': {'coins': ['coin1', 'coin2'], 'shibakunumber': 2, 'oslink': 'somelink'}}
```

Comment: Is this not working?

Comment: What is the content of your 'Shibaku0.json'?

Comment: @MYouseif How would I call and print only the "oslink", I have this code for it `@client.command(aliases = ["shib, shibaku, Shib"])
async def Shibaku(ctx, int = 0):

  if int == 0:
    with open('Shibaku0.json') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
      for oslink in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]["oslink"]:
        await ctx.send(oslink)` But it send the link letter by letter instead of the entire thing

Comment: I declared it as a variable and printed it `oslink = users[str(ctx.author.id)]["oslink"]
      await ctx.send(oslink)`

Comment: What you are doing there is looping over oslink value. just send the `coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]["oslink"]` instead and remove the `for oslin in ...`

Comment: Would you happen to know how to hyperlink a message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527464/clickable-link-inside-message-discord-py